# A variation of the two envelopes problem

Tags: probability

You choose between one of two identical envelopes, where one contains double *or* half the amount of money in the other. You open one, find \$100 inside and are given the oppurtunity to switch. Should you?

My solution is as follows: Let $x$ be the amount of money behind envelope 1, then envelope 2 contains either $2x$ or $0.5x$, with equal probability. If we initially choose envelope 1, then the unchosen envelope will contain \$50 (if $0.5x$ is behind envelope 2) or \$200 (if $2x$ is behind envelope 2) with equal probability. If we initially choose envelope 2, the unchosen envelope will also hold \$50 (if $2x$ is behind envelope 2) or \$200 (if $0.5x$ is behind envelope 2) with equal probability. The expected amount of money obtained by switching is therefore $0.5*\$50 + 0.5*\$200 = \$125$.

However, according to my teacher there is another (possibly more correct) solution which shows that switching envelopes does *not* change the expected outcome. What might this other solution be?

Comment: Why do you think the variation matters? What do you find deficient about standard resolutions of the two envelopes problem (as can be found e.g. on Wikipedia)?

Comment: @MeesdeVries I didn't think this problem was exactly the same because firstly, the second envelope contains half or double that of the first (rather than double), and secondly we are allowed to see the amount in the first before having to decide whether to switch.

Comment: To my understanding, in the standard two envelopes problem, the other envelope also contains half or double the amount in the other envelope. I understand that seeing the $\$100$ is not standard in the two envelopes problem, but my question is why you think that matters for the resolution of the problem. Specifically, what do you find dissatisfying about the standard resolutions, when applied to this situation?

Comment: @MeesdeVries I realise now that if we define x to be the smaller amount of money (rather than the ammount in what we label as 'envelope 1'), then that part becomes the same as the standard two envelopes problem. However, in the standard problem, the expected amount of money obtained by both swapping and remaining with the original choice is the same (1.5x). If we inspect the amount of money in our first envelope and find it to be $100, we have 100% probability of recieving that amount if we don't switch, so doesn't that alter the expected value of both choices?

Answer (score 1):

Let T be the combined amount of money in the two envelopes. It is equally likely that your envelope has T/3 or 2T/3, and the expectation is T/2. It is also equally likely that the other envelope has 2T/3 or T/3, and its expectation also T/2. So there is no point in switching.

Say I put \$50 in each of nine envelopes, and \$200 in one other. I shuffle these ten envelopes, and pick one. Then I put \$100 in another envelope, and give it and the randomly selected envelope to you. It is true that one contains twice the amount in the other. It is true that if you pick one, you have a 50% chance to have the higher, or lower, of those two.

But it isn't true that, if your envelope has \$100, there is a 50% chance it is the higher or lower one. The error in your solution is associating a value with being the higher or lower. My solution doesn't do that.